# Texture paint not showing in render mode

Tags: texture-painting

i made a texture paint for my model in Blender and saved it for later, i reopened my project added back my texture nothing special, i then started to work on adding pores with a alpha for the mask brush but it turned wrong and i couldn't erase what the "F Mask" brush did, so i closed and opened my work back but now for some reason when i am painting on my texture in the "Texture paint" mode, it wont show the changes in the render mode :

[image: Prepare for unforseen consequences]

I can't figure this out my project is clean i have only one material named "Material.003" and one texture named "skintest" it started messing up when i tried to add the alpha pic of some pores to the mask brush by guessing...

If someone knows whats up please let me know,

[image]

[image]

If i move the UV texture it does shows the changes in the render but the Paint brush is ignored by the render...

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of your node tree?

Comment: There, hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

Ok so found out that i need to **save** the texture before rendering in **UV/ImageEditor** for the brush work to show up but i dont understand because i was able to paint in real time earlier, i even remade a texture so i am kind of lost, anyway i guess i am gonna have to work with saving between each stroke...